# RMI server interface (dispatcher) methods throwing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to implement a 2-player network quiz game using RMI. I have a `DispatcherInterface` (interface) and `Dispatcher` (implementing the for the former) respecting RMI architecture.
The server model has `User` and `Theme` where a `Quiz` would be in a specific theme, my idea was that when a `User` connects into a `Theme` they'd be added into a `Map<User,Theme> waitingList` until another `User` comes along to play against them.

My problem lies in the implementation, while trying to implement a simple setter method for adding users to the waiting list I get the following error:

```
Error occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/sql/SQLException
```

Which did not make sense to me since my class path is well defined for the RMI registry and the compile/run commands.

```
public interface DispatcherInterface extends Remote {
    public User login(ReceiverInterface client, String email, String password) throws RemoteException;
    public void addToWaitingList(int userID, Theme theme) throws RemoteException;
    public void addToWaitingList(User user, Theme theme) throws RemoteException;

}
```

The first method works perfectly with no problems while the other one doesn't regardless of its implementation (tried a simple `System.out.print("test")`), however I find it inconvenient as I have to loop over the list of connected users in order to get the `User` instance I need to add to my `waitingList`. So idealy I am hoping to be able to pass an instance of `User` to the method.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
    public ReceiverInterface client;
    public int id;
    public String pseudo;
    ...
}
```

I do not understand why I can't pass the a `User` object to the method, especially since it's serializable.

For completeness sake, for the client part, I have implemented similarly a `ReceiverInterface` and `Receiver` that communicate with the server through a proxy (DispatcherInterface)

```
public class Receiver implements ReceiverInterface {
    private DispatcherInterface = proxy;
    private User user;
    private String serverIP;

    public Receiver(String serverIP) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException {
        this.serverIP = serverIP;
        Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(serverIP);
        this.proxy = (DispatcherInterface) registry.lookup("QuizApp");
    }
    ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:**
I use an IDE (IntelliJ) to run my code, it uses the following command:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk/bin/java -javaagent:/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/lib/idea_rt.jar=41683:/opt/intellij-idea-ultimate-edition/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/rand/gm4/JAVA/QuizApp/out/production/QuizApp:/home/rand/gm4/JAVA/QuizApp/lib/miglayout-swing-5.2.jar:/home/rand/gm4/JAVA/QuizApp/lib/miglayout-core-5.2.jar:/home/rand/gm4/JAVA/QuizApp/lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.23.1.jar server.Run
```

Which is in better terms (without the `.jar` dependencies), run from the project path is:

```
javac -d out/production/[project_name] src/server/Run.java
javac -d out/production/[project_name] src/client/Run.java
rmiregistry -J-Djava.class.path=out/production/[project_name]/
java -cp out/production/[project_name] server.Run
java -cp out/production/[project_name] client.Run
```

Comment: What version of java are you using to execute your code and what is the command you are using to run your code?  This is probably a module issue if you are on Java9+. Also make sure you dont have an extra import somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Deadron I tried java10.0.2, java9.0.4 and java1.8.0 but nothing worked.

Comment: This is definetly a module issue. Please show us the exact command you use to run your code as well as the result of java -version. Also please run a search in your code and make sure the SQLException is a valid dependency of your code and not a auto-completion typo.

Comment: @Deadron I edited the question to include the compile and run commands, and yes SQLException is a valid dependency, I'm using an `sqlite` database in my program (JDBC). Thank you for you time!

Answer (score 0):

You are using jdk 10 to execute your code. In jdk 9 some of the code base was moved into modules and no longer avaliable by default, java.sql is in one of these non root module. You need to use "--add-modules java.sql"  with the java command to make the java.sql package avaliable at runtime.

Since you are using intellij to run the code the following doc might help explain how to setup intellij to include this module when run from the ide. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-java-9-module-system.html